# normalizing number between 2 ranges

Tags: normalization, normalize

I know this may be a fairly basic thing but I'm having a lot of difficulty with it. I have some numbers which could be anywhere between 0.449999988079 and 10.0. What I would like to do is normalise these numbers so they are between 0.1 and 0.5. Could anyone help with achieving this please.

Thanks

Comment: Do you specifically want 0.449999988079, or are you using 16 bit floating point numbers and want 0.45?

Comment: Well to make calculations easier it could be 0.45 as accuracy to more than 2 decimal places is not essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function normalize(num, fromMin, fromMax, toMin, toMax)
{
    return toMin + (num - fromMin)/(fromMax - fromMin) * (toMax - toMin)
}
```